# Как создать массив который можно заполнять до тех пор пока пользователь вводит числа

Tags: java

Как создать массив который можно заполнять  до тех пор, пока пользователь 
вводит числа.
   Вот как я примерно себе это представлял:

```
    int n = 1;
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    if (arr.length == 0) {
        n += 1;
    }
```

Comment: В данном случае по семантике лучше подходит `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если очень грубо, то так (и не забудьте определить кодовый символ для выхода из процесса ввода, в данном примере -1):

```
int[] arr = new int[0];
int value;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while ((value = scanner.nextInt()) != -1) {
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
    arr[arr.length - 1] = value;
}
```

ну и для избавления от всего этого кошмара используются различные реализации интерфейса `List`

Answer (score 4):

В Java массивы имеют фиксированный размер. Вам подойдет ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
while (smth) {
   array.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как ответил предыдущий участник Naatsms, Вам действительно подойдёт ArrayList.
На начальном этапе изучения Java в качестве пользовательского ввода можете использовать аргумент командной строки для ввода в массив значения пользователя. Но не забывайте, что если массив целочисленный(ArrayList a = new ArrayList<>;), то необходимо привести аргумент командной строки к типу int(либо к тому целочисленному типу, который Вы используете:
int x = (int) args[0]; Причем номера элемента массива указывается в соответствии с номером аргумента командой строки.